# How to do indexing in Python from last number to first

Tags: python

Suppose the integer string `2080880579`.

I want to reach this:

```
(2*10)+(0*9)+(8*8)+(0*7)+(8*6)+(8*5)+(0*4)+(5*3)+(7*2)
```

And the final answer and number should be `201`.

The logic is:

```
(integer * position of the number)
```

Where `2` is in position `10`, `0` is in position `9`, etc.

How can I reach this?

What I've tried so far is:

```
national = '2080880579'

for n in national:
    print(f'the index number of {n} is {national.index(n)}', end='.\n')
    # print the multiple and calculate them
```

I tried some example codes but it failed.

Comment: See `enumerate`.

Comment: Why no `(9*1)`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode because some calculation should be done to check if the last digit is correct or not (in fact to see if whole string digit is correct).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode that's a way to check if entered national_id is correct or not, and the last digit should not be included in multiple process.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode that's an algorithm to check if the other digits are correct, and then last digit would be a number based on calculation (for example, multiple all numbers and add with each other, then divide on 10. there are some if to reach the last digit). I edited the question and removed that last digit since it's not necessary

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I appreciate your concern. Suppose you want to check if your id `2080880579` is correct or not. Calculation `2...7` (sum, divide, multiple) checks if 9 could be correct or not. If yes, then your id number is correct.

Comment: @AKX thanks, most of the answers are based on `enumerate`

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Suppose your national_id. You want to create an algorithm to check if your national_id is correct. And you want to check other ones too. That's the whole story.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode https://github.com/SaeedFazlollahzadeh/code_melli

Comment: Ok, Melli code was a useful hint.

Comment: @azro all the answers are right and fill my need. Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must be the shortest one-liner:

```py
result = sum(i * int(c) for i, c in enumerate(national[::-1], 1))
print(result)  # 210
```

Or if you want to omit the last number from the calculation, then use:

```py
result = sum(i * int(c) for i, c in enumerate(national[-2::-1], 2))
print(result)  # 201
```

Comment: In fact the calculation should be `201`, I edited the question. But if I remove the last digit to be a string of nine digits, I do not get number `201`.

Comment: This is the most concise answer, but that does not mean it's the best answer for a newer programmer...

Comment: @Gary02127 I generally agree, although it depends. I would be challenged to figure out how it works.

Comment: `sum(i * int(national[-i]) for i in range(2, 11))` is eight characters shorter than the "This must be the shortest one-liner" one and already gets 201 :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Shortest out of the posted :-P Also, yours expects `national` to be always 10 characters long, which is a constraint.

Comment: Yes, after a long back and forth they finally somewhat revealed that they're apparently doing Iranian national ID numbers and those appear to always be 10 digits long. Plus yours might also get different lengths wrong, for example if a number had 6 digits and you were supposed to multiply with 10,9,8,7,6,5.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode That's unexpected. I thought it would be 6,5,4,3,2,1 or wherever they wanted to stop. Anyway, that seems to suit the OP's needs, so I'll let him to decide what to do with it if things go out of control :)

Answer (score 3):

```py
national = '2080880579'
text = ''
textsum = 0
for i in range(len(national)-1):
    text = text + f'({national[i]}*{-i + len(national)}) + '
    textsum = textsum + (int(national[i]) * (-i + len(national)))
text = text[:len(text)-3]
print(text)
print(textsum)
```

Output:

```
(2*10) + (0*9) + (8*8) + (0*7) + (8*6) + (8*5) + (0*4) + (5*3) + (7*2)
201
```

Comment: Thanks, I really love your answer because shows the calculation. I use the part it shows calculation as it really helps me:)

Answer (score 1):

Based off of my understanding of the post, and the information given, you will want to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). This yields pairs of `(index, item)` from an iterable.

If this answer does not accurately address the question, please comment and let me know so it can be fixed.

```py
national = '208088057'
mySum = 0
for idx, n in enumerate(national):
    print(f'the index number of {n} is {idx}', end='.\n')
    mySum += (len(national)-idx+1) * int(n)
print(mySum)
#201
```

Or, in a 1 liner:

```py
>>> sum((len(national)-idx+1) * int(n) for idx,n in enumerate(national))
201
```

Alternately, you can use the reverse of the string

Comment: In fact the calculation should be `201`, I edited the question. But if I remove the last digit to be a string of nine digits, I do not get number `201`.

Comment: That is because removing the 9 changes the algorithm a bit. I have included a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip (pair) your value, and the range from 10 to 0

```
# national[:-1]    >  2 0 8 0 8 8 0 5 7
# range(10, 1, -1) > 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

Then multiply each pair, and sum the total

```
national = '2080880579'

print(
    sum((int(n) * r for n, r in zip(national[:-1], range(len(national), 1, -1))))
)
# 201
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the other poster that `enumerate` is a great function, it's not as helpful here as it could be in other places. I think the better trick here is processing the string in reverse order and just keeping a counter. So:

```
national = '2080880579'
counter = 1
result = 0
for digit in national[::-1]:
    result += int(digit) * counter
    counter += 1
```

You could still use `enumerate` as follows:

```
national = '2080880579'
result = 0
for index, digit in enumerate(national[::-1], 1):
    result += int(digit) * index
```

The enumerate index starts at 0 by default, but you can choose a start value with a second argument.

UPDATE:
Not adding that last char seems strange, but if that is what you truly desire, the above would become:

```
national = '2080880579'
result = 0
for index, digit in enumerate(national[-2::-1], 2): ####
    result += int(digit) * index
```

to skip the last digit, `[::-1], 1` becomes `[-2::-1], 2`

Comment: In fact the calculation should be `201`, I edited the question. But if I remove the last digit to be a string of nine digits, I do not get number `201`.

Comment: When I run your updated code, `print(result)` at the end with no indentation, I get the number 6. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Nope. My code is not running properly. Somehow the enumerate call is breaking what should otherwise work. I will repost a working version

Comment: @Saeed I had an error in my text-reversing slice which is now fixed. Apologies...